# how Apache Cordova works

Tags: cordova, web, cross-platform

Im just curious and would like to know if anyone could provide an explination to how Apache Cordova converts a web application to a cross platform application.

Ive read this explination: https://blogs.sap.com/2014/07/27/what-is-cordova-and-how-does-it-work/

But i guess my question is what use dose a `WebView` have in all this exactly? Surely native apps are'nt rendered in `WebView`s, so what purpose dose it have with the cross platform applications? Is it converted into something?

I'd appreciate it if someone could clear the air.

Comment: The user interface is s a web page shown in the browser control like the page you linked explains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova uses a WebView to render your application built with HTML/JS/CSS. It's a mini embedded browser inside a native app (webview). Then Cordova uses plugins to access the native layer (SDK), for both Android and iOS.
The purpose is to be able to build apps using HTML/JS/CSS and then pilot the native functions of each platform (iOS & Android) via JavaScript and publish to both platforms using a single code base.

Comment: ok, that makes perfect sence, thanks!